# how to retrieve list of controls in a form of project A and then load them in Project B

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

NOTE: Project A and B is of different window of visual studio they are not on the same solution.This is for winforms not WPF project..

I want to get all of controls on a project A then when i get them ill use them in project B how will i do that?

Comment: Are you talking design time or runtime

Comment: You wanna make set of controls usable in both project or you wanna take controls from existing project, or from compiled file or somethign else? Explain please.

Comment: design time sir mark.

Comment: no i dont wanna make set of controls cause control on project A is already made and i just wanna get the list of controls then use them on Project B. project B is on runtime while Project A is on design time.

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is not enough to comment, but I'd like to say why don't you just import 
files from project a and use it on project b so you have copy of controls in project a in a .cs files and import it contents to project b , that would be easier if I were you.

Hope you understands

Poom

Comment: i understand what your saying but im not creating new project/file then use the existing project/file. hmmm how will i explained this.im creating a program lets say project B is already an exe(already running). now B supposed to retrieve the controls on Project A(which is on design time).. i hope you undertstand what im trying to reach out.

Comment: Oh I understand,So sorry . bytheway what does design time mean? Before debugging?

Comment: @lankean Please State that project B is already exe so that other programmers can help you out easier by wheather edit your post or accept my edit